# Webforms and MVC hosting side by side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an ASP.net webforms web application running Umbraco CMS, this is running just fine and dandy. I have also created a separate MVC web application which forms part of the site above (an insurance quote engine).

Is it possible to simply upload the MVC application (separate folder) and run within my existing web app i.e. /mvcapplication? Should it just work or do you have to do some web.config hacks?

p.s. There are similar questions but not answered

Comment: My gut tells me that no, it's not possible, and also that it's not a good idea anyway. With that said, we may need more information: which version of IIS? Which version(s) of .NET? Do you need to share session state?

Comment: IIS 7.5 and no it doesn't need to share session state. The MVC application is completely independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can but you have to treated in your IIS as a separate web-application under the folder of your web-form site. In another word put your MVC app in  your Webform site folder and then make the  MVC folder as a new application under the web-form this way you do not have to deal with web-config and each app webforms and mvc would use it own config.

Comment: the only other case is to treat the webb forms as wbsite so each forms compiles at runtime on iis otherwise I do not really see any other solutiuons'